# Div background not appearing in live ie and firefox

Tags: html, css

I have been playing with this for a long time and can not get it to work.

The `div #wrapper` background .png appears offline fine in both ie and firefox but fails to show in live, any help would be gratefully received.

Rod

http://www.goforitni.com/facebook/welcome/welcome-unliked.html

Answer (score 0):

That's because http://www.goforitni.com/facebook/images/background.png can't be loaded (probably doesn't exist). You can check in firebug.

Comment: Boy do I feel like a chump, over and over previous posts talked about the location but genius me had the suffix as .PNG not .png

Simple but of course I had to ask the question on stackoverflow before I spotted my error!

Thank you to all who helped.

Rod

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your path to the images folder is incorrect in the CSS.

You're using `../images/background.png` - are you sure it shouldn't just be `images/background.png`?

Perhaps it's been cached locally and that's why it displays for you.

Comment: The left hand Div background (green) is in the same images folder and it shows...

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the correct path to your background background.png

```
background-image: url('../images/background.png')
```

correct this line.

and also you have some problems like

```
# html body{
```

(line 11 )

and

```
z-index:10; } }
```

in line 145